# Get notification wether iOS device is close?

Tags: ios, ibeacon

Is it any protocol that notes when a device get close to the device runs same application, i.e. to device with user is standing in the same station? Can I fetch this with iBeacon? It seems Apple Friends application show realtime position of users I subscripted for. Is it possible know of proximity data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make your iOS app itself advertise an iBeacon packet:

[Turning an iOS Device into an iBeacon](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/turning_an_ios_device_into_an_ibeacon)

And then use iBeacon ranging/monitoring APIs from Core Location to detect other such "iBeacons" (= users of the same app) nearby.

Another option is MultipeerConnectivity, which works a bit similar. You have an "advertiser" which broadcasts your device's presence to anyone nearby (via Bluetooth or Wi-Fi), and a "browser" for detecting such devices:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/multipeerconnectivity

Both of these generally won't work in the background though. You can detect iBeacon in the background, but can't advertise it in the background. You can use a pre-established MultipeerConnectivity session in the background, but can't discover and establish new sessions.

Answer (score 0):

After scanning and monitoring for beacon regions, every second you get beacons near you (in range) in:

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didRangeBeacons beacons: [CLBeacon], in region: CLBeaconRegion) {
// here you can see every beacon that is in range
}
```

To see the distance between you and the beacon, access beacon.proximity attribute and if you're interested in received signal strength access beacon.rssi.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean detecting iOS devices close to each other, it's kind of possible to do it with beacons. You can place a beacon somewhere, and when a user is near the beacon and `didRangeBeacons` is fired, send the user's data received from `didRangeBeacons` (containing their distance from the beacon and beacon's info) to the server, do some calculations there and if there is two devices near a beacon, send a push notification to them.